# Python error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)"

Tags: python, csv

I do computing at school but their version of **python** is different to the one I have at home and every time I try to run a file I did at school on my home computer it says "

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position
>   11: ordinal not in range(128)"

Any help is appreciated

**Here is my code so far.**

```
classc = int(input("WHich classes scores do you want to see 1 or 2 or 3"))
if classc ==1:
    import csv


    print("H")
    with open("class1.csv","r") as csv1file:
        csvfile1reader = csv.reader(csv1file)
        csv1 = []
        for row in csvfile1reader:
            if len (row) != 0:
                csv1 = csv1 + [row]



        print("Here are the scores for class1 in aphabetical order!")
    import operator

    hl = open ("class1.csv","r")

    csvo = csv.reader(hl,delimiter='0')

    sort1 = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    for row in sort1:
        print (row)
    print("these are the highest to lowest score")    
h2 = open ("class1.csv","r")
csvo = csv.reader(hl,delimiter=' ')
sort2 = sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for row in sort2:
        print (row)
import csv

with open('class1.csv') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle)
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        user, *scores = row
        average = sum([int(score) for score in scores]) / len(scores)
        print (
            "{user} has average of {average}".format(user=user, average=average)
        )
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error message including the line number?

Comment: …and the Python version as that can affect how to properly handle unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0x90` is indeed out of range for ASCII, which only covers `0x00` to `0x7f`. The file may be in some Unicode encoding, or it may be in some 8-bit encoding, in the ISO-8859 family.  Once you have found that out, open your file with the `codecs` module.  Supposing your encoding is ISO-8859-1:

```
with codecs.open('class1.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1') as handle:
    reader = csv.reader(handle)
```

Comment: The choice of 8859-1 is often a good guess, but if it's wrong, you won't get any warning, just incorrect data. Better than wild guessing would be for the OP to actually figure out the proper encoding, perhaps in a separate question, perhaps with more information as explained in the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info).